# No puedo guardar valores mediante POST - laravel vue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

Estoy intentando guardar los datos que envío desde la vista Event.vue al método storeEvent del controlador EventController  pero me da error 422 y no encuentro hasta el momento el problema.

El modelo Event tiene una relación muchos a muchos con el modelo Categories, y también Event tiene una relación muchos a muchos con el modelo Coins, es por esta razón que ocupo vue-multiselect ya que el usuario puede seleccionar varias categoriras o varias coin para el mismo evento

Event.vue

```
<template>
   <form v-on:submit.prevent="createdEvent" class="form-horizontal">
     <div class="form-group row">
       <label>Titulo</label>
       <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="25" v-model="title">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group row">
       <label>*Cryptodivisas</label>
       <multiselect v-model="coinvalue" :options="coins"
                    :multiple="true" label="name" 
                    track-by="id" placeholder="Seleccione">
       </multiselect>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group row">
       <label>*Categoría</label>
       <multiselect v-model="categoryvalue" :options="categories"
                    :multiple="true" label="name" 
                    track-by="id" placeholder="Seleccione">
       </multiselect>
     </div> 
     <div class="col-sm-12">
       <button class="btn" type="submit">Crear evento</button>
     </div>
   </form>
 </template>
 <script>
    import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';
    export default {  
      components: { 
        Multiselect,
      },
      props: ['auth'],     
      data () {
        return {
            user:           {},
            title:          '',
            coins:          [],
            coinvalue:      [],
            categories:     [],
            categoryvalue:  [], 
       }
      },
      created() {
        this.getCoins();
        this.getCategories();
      },
      mounted() {
        this.user = JSON.parse(this.auth);
      },
      methods: {
        getCoins(){
            let urlCoin = '/dashboard/coins';
            axios.get(urlCoin)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.coins = response.data;
                })
                .catch((err) => {

                })
        },
        getCategories(){
            let urlCategories = '/dashboard/categories';
            axios.get(urlCategories)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.categories = response.data;
                })
                .catch((err) => {

                })
        },
        createdEvent(){
            let urlEvent = '/dashboard/newEvent';
            const eventData = {
                'id'            : this.user.id,
                'title'         : this.title,
                'coin'          : this.coinvalue,
                'category'      : this.categoryvalue,
            }
            console.log(eventData);
            axios.post(urlEvent, eventData)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(ok);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err.response.data);
                })
        }
 </script>
```

storeEvent (EventController)

```
   public function storeEvent(Request $request)
   {
      $this->validate($request, [
                    'title'    => 'required|max:25',
                    'coin'     => 'required',
                    'category' => 'required',
            ]);

            $userAuth = Auth::user()->id;
            $userEvent = $request->id;
            if($userAuth === $userEvent){
                $event = new Event;
                $event->user_id = $userEvent;
                $event->title = $request->title;   
                if($event->save()){
                    $event->coins()->attach($request->coin);
                    $event->categories()->attach($request->category);
                    return response()->json([
                            'status' => 'Muy bien!',
                            'msg' => 'Tu evento ya fue creado con éxito.',
                            ], 200);
                }
                else {
                    return response()->json([
                                'status' => 'Error!',
                                'msg' => 'No pudimos crear tu evento.',
                            ], 401);
                }
           }
    }
```

Pienso que el problema puede estar cuando le asigno los valores a la sección coin()->attach() y category()->attach(), pero no tengo idea como solucionarlo debido a mi inexperiencia en la herramienta.

El sistema estaba hecho íntegramente en Laravel y funcionaba sin problemas, ahora que se esta actualizando con Vue empezó a dar inconvenientes.

¿Alguna idea? ocupo Laravel 5,6, Vuejs 2, Axios y Vue-multiselect 2

Comment: El error 422 mayormente es por errores de validación, recuerde que en el multiselect al momento de seleccionar se guardan objetos y no id's como seguramente lo hacía con blade. Tenga cuidado con eso en principio el 422 es por validate

Comment: Efectivamente, ¿como puedo trabajar eso? ¿como puedo pasar los valores del objeto a ids?

Comment: Hice lo que me recomendaste, `let idcoin = this.coinvalue.map(e=> e.id);  y  let idcategory = this.categoryvalue.map(e=> e.id);`  y me arroja este error `category undefined` `coin undefined`

Comment: Por consola muestro el objeto que mando por Axios `console.log(eventData);` y ahí veo que las variables category y coin están con valores undefined

Comment: `let idcoin = this.coinvalue.map(e=> e.id); let idcategory = this.categoryvalue.map(e=> e.id); const eventData = {'id' : user.id,
'title': this.title, 'coin': this.idcoin, 'category': this.idcategory} `

Comment: al hacer `this.idcoin` está intentando buscar en data esa propiedad , pero `idcoin` no pertenece a la instancia solo es una variable. debe hacer simplemente `'coin':idcoin` lo mismo para `idcategory`

Comment: uuufff error de novato, no me había fijado en eso, ahora van bien los datos, necesito sacar otro error relacionado casi a lo mismo, la diferencia está que en vez de ocupar multiselect con la opción multiple, la ocupo para mostrar solo un dato seleccionado, ahí me está dando error. No sé si hacer una nueva pregunta, de todas formas, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que al intentar enviar los valores por `post` con `axios`, el valor de `coinvalue` y `categoryvalue` son **objetos** seleccionados , pero lo que se necesita son solo los `id` para utilizarlos en el controlador,

Para lograr esto, antes de enviar los datos, puede filtrarlos con la finalidad obtener un nuevo `array` con solo los  `id's` , para esto puede utilizar `map` de la siguiente forma.

```
createdEvent(){
  let urlEvent = '/dashboard/newEvent';
  let idcoin = this.coinvalue.map(e=> e.id); 
  let idcategory = this.categoryvalue.map(e=> e.id);
  const eventData = {
      'id' : this.user.id,
      'title' : this.title,
      'coin' : idcoin ,
      'category': idcategory 
 }
 axios.post(urlEvent, eventData) ...
```